# Unable to query LINQ fields backed by private member

Tags: c#, linq

I have this C# class declaration:

```
public class Cookie : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    .....
    [Column(Name = "CookieID", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "CookieName")]
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(@"Name");
        }
    }
}
```

I perform the following Query in VB.net:

```
m_Data.Cookies.Any(Function(x) x.Name = "selectedproject")
```

which is met with the error "The member 'DataModel.Cookie.Name' has no supported translation to SQL."

Querying the Id property instead , or changing the name property as follows:

```
[Column(Name = "CookieName")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

works fine, but then i cannot generate the PropertyChanged event, which I need to inform the UI of the field change. Is there a way to make the property translatable to SQL, while retaining the notification ability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Linq executes the query, any property in it must be mapped to the database, as the SQL query can't run C# code.

Change your code to:

```
[NotMapped]
private string _name;
[Column(Name = "CookieName")]
public string Name
```

(Actually, I'm not sure the private property will be mapped to SQL, but I've added the [NotMapped] attribute just in case).

By mapping the property with the getter/setter to the database, you can query by it (when reading the data from the database, it will query against the table column).

Note: that as soon as data is read from the DB the setter will be called, so you should modify your code so that OnPropertyChanged is only called when _name is not null.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I assumed the setter property was only called by the database consumer end, and never by the provider end. That is why I backed the field by a private property. Of course this will remove the mapping from the property to the field, so it will not be queryable.